# Restructure data (which is in multiple data frames already) into different multiple data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I am new to R and I am having trouble with finding a way how to restructure my data.

Currently I have 365 different data frames, each representing a day of the year. In each data frame there is point of sales data, so how many items of a product is sold at each store per day. There are four columns in each data frame; namely ShopId, ArticleId, Date (which is constant in one data frame), and AmountSold.

Now I want to restructure my data frames to be able to forecast how many items I need per product per store per day. I would like to do this by clustering either all data points corresponding to a certain store (ShopId), or by clustering all data points corresponding to a certain product (ArticleId) in separate data frames. The problem is that I do not know how to do this. I already have a list of all my data frames, which I coded like this:

```
l.df <- lapply(ls(), function(x) if (class(get(x)) == "data.frame") get(x))
```

I also have a list of all ArticleId's occurring in the data frames:
`AllArticleId`, and a list of all ShopId's occurring in the data frames: `AllShopId`.

Can anyone tell me how I can restructure my data?

Comment: `df <- do.call(rbind, l.df)` should combine all the data frames from your list into a single data frame.

Comment: Then you can use `aggregate` to perform a function over a specific group.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try below:

```
library(dplyr);
file_names <- dir() # Location of individual sales files
agg_df     <- do.call(rbind,lapply(file_names,read.csv)) 

# Median sale per Article ID
agg_df = agg_df %>% group_by(ArticleID) %>% 
                      mutate(mSlByArtId = median(AmountSold));

# Median sale per Shop ID
agg_df = agg_df %>% group_by(ShopID) %>% 
                      mutate(mSlByShpId = median(AmountSold));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is, for example, how you can perform a `mean` for given shop grouped by `shopId`:

```
 dl <- list()
 dl[[1]] <- data.frame(
   shopId = rep(1:4, each = 2),
   ArticleId = c(1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2),
   date = 1:8,
   AmountSoled = 5
 )

 dl[[2]] <- data.frame(
   shopId = rep(1:4, each = 2),
   ArticleId = c(2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1),
   date = 1:8,
   AmountSoled = 5
 )


#  dl
# [[1]]
#   shopId ArticleId date AmountSoled
# 1      1         1    1           5
# 2      1         1    2           5
# 3      2         3    3           5
# 4      2         2    4           5
# 5      3         3    5           5
# 6      3         2    6           5
# 7      4         1    7           5
# 8      4         2    8           5
# 
# [[2]]
#   shopId ArticleId date AmountSoled
# 1      1         2    1           5
# 2      1         1    2           5
# 3      2         3    3           5
# 4      2         2    4           5
# 5      3         4    5           5
# 6      3         4    6           5
# 7      4         3    7           5
# 8      4         1    8           5


 df <- do.call(rbind, dl)
 df
#    shopId ArticleId date AmountSoled
# 1       1         1    1           5
# 2       1         1    2           5
# 3       2         3    3           5
# 4       2         2    4           5
# 5       3         3    5           5
# 6       3         2    6           5
# 7       4         1    7           5
# 8       4         2    8           5
# 9       1         2    1           5
# 10      1         1    2           5
# 11      2         3    3           5
# 12      2         2    4           5
# 13      3         4    5           5
# 14      3         4    6           5
# 15      4         3    7           5
# 16      4         1    8           5

 aggregate(df, by = list(df$shopId), mean)
#   Group.1 shopId ArticleId date AmountSoled
# 1       1      1      1.25  1.5           5
# 2       2      2      2.50  3.5           5
# 3       3      3      3.25  5.5           5
# 4       4      4      1.75  7.5           5
```